# Sum all the elements in a matrix using a loop

Tags: r, matrix

In R, I have a 5x5 matrix called `P` like this:

```
1  3  0  0  0
0  3  0  0  0
0  3  1  0  0
0  3  0  1  0
0  3  0  0  1
```

and want to sum all its elements. I know I can do `sum(P)` and get 19. But I want to do this using a for or while loop.

One idea was to do

```
result <- 0
for(i in col(P)) { result <- result + sum(i)}
```

however this gives me that the sum (`result`) is 75 and even after printing the result variable, I can't understand why.

Comment: The 75 comes from summing all elements of the output of `col(P)`. But as Ronak said, using a for loop for this kind of thing is rarely the best solution in `R`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure, why you want to do this but we can use a C-like looping structure which loops for each column and row and take the `sum` of each element.

```
result = 0
for (i in 1:ncol(P)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(P)) {
    result = result + P[i, j]
 }
}

result
#V1 
#19
```

---

With a `while` loop

```
i = 1
result = 0
while(i <= length(P)) {
  result = result + P[i]
  i = i + 1
}

result
#[1] 19
```

---

Another option as suggested by @zx8754 is to convert it into a vector and loop on each element

```
result = 0
for (i in as.vector(P)) {
  result = result + i  
}

result
#[1] 19
```